# Sitecore 9.3 Solr ContentSearch does not get the right language

Tags: solr, content-search, language-fallback

I have a site with the language english (en -> default language) and portuguese (pt-BR). Now I have the problem that on the portugese website there are shown items of the english language version. The items are in the solr index.
Sitecore version: 9.3

This is the code which starts the search:

```
        string indexName = "list_item_search_index_" + Sitecore.Context.Database.Name;
        List<ListSearchResult> result = SearchManager.ContentSearch(searchword, indexName, expr, true);
```

This is the config for Sitecore.Solr.SearchIndexes.config:

```
      <index id="list_item_search_index_master" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
        //other configs
        <enableItemLanguageFallback>true</enableItemLanguageFallback>
        <enableFieldLanguageFallback>true</enableFieldLanguageFallback>
      </index>
```

I already enabled languagefallback for this index and rebuilt the index. It is still showing the false language version. I tried it with the master database.

Comment: When you look at the raw solr query, what language do you see being queried?

Comment: Add language filter to your search predicates might help

Comment: You can do a filter by language like this  .Filter(x => x.Language == Context.Language.Name) if you are using an IQueryable type

Comment: Post the code of `SearchManager.ContentSearch` method

Comment: There are two languages that are indexed. Once the "en" and once pt-BR in the raw index of solr.

Comment: The code of SearchManager.ContentSearch is below.

Comment: Please check the index config in Solr whether both languages are added so that the Solr would store both language data in it.

Comment: There are two languages that are indexed. Once the "en" and once pt-BR in the raw index of solr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case I would maybe check whether you don't have any ComputedFields. This is usually causing trouble as language fallback is not applied of course automatically for these fields.

I assume that the current code is missing getting field value based on language so something like this: `item.Database.GetItem(indexableItem.itemid)`

You need to add second parameter and provide also language/culture so something like this: `item.Database.GetItem(indexableItem.itemid, Sitecore.Globalization.Language.Parse(indexableItem.Culture.Name))`

Comment: This was exactly the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you don't need the Language fallback enabled in the first place.

Items with language fallback enabled and don't have the pt-BR version, Sitecore will use the fallback language (in this case I believe `en`) for indexing.
If you don't want this to happen, you could turn it off.